# Can't un-silence ringer without reboot on 5.1.1 / Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, volume-control, 5.1-lollipop

I turned the "bell" volume down and now it won't turn up again!

When I press volume up, I see the slider appear next to a bell symbol, but the slider is at zero, and doesn't budge when I press Vol Up. If I drag the slider it struggles to follow my finger, strobing between where I'm trying to drag it to, and zero. As soon as I let go it goes back to zero.

Anybody else found this? Is there a fix? Turning it off and on again seems to work.